# How to save buffer in subfolder

Tags: context

I'm wondering whether it is possible, and if so how, to save the contents of a ConTeXt buffer to file. Well, I know that the command `\savebuffer[<buffername>][<filename>]` exists, but it saves the file in the same location as the `.tex` file. I was hoping I could save the file in a subdirectory, say `./temp`, to avoid cluttering up the main working directory. But that doesn't work. MWE:

```
\starttext

\startbuffer[code]
-- some lua code for examples sake
local x = 2
local y = math.sqrt(x)
\stopbuffer

% works
\savebuffer
  [code]
  [code.lua]

% doesn't work
\savebuffer
  [code]
  [/temp/code.lua]

\stoptext
```

Comment: Have you tried without the forward slash at the beginning? Like `\savebuffer[code][temp/code.lua]`?

Comment: I did try that, and a couple of variations, unsuccessfully. *But* you mentioning it now has given me a brainwave! I'll post a self-answer as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, `\savebuffer` attaches a prefix `<jobname>-` to the saved file. (So, for example, the call `\savebuffer[code][code.lua]` in a file `foo.tex` saves the buffer as `foo-code.lua`.) Thus, doing the naive thing

```
\savebuffer
  [code]
  [temp/code.lua]
```

is no good, as it would attempt to save the buffer as `<jobname>-temp/code.lua`. Instead, make use the *other* way of calling `\savebuffer`, which is:

```
\savebuffer
  [list=<buffer name(s)>, prefix=<'yes' or 'no'>, file=<filename>]
```

Then you can do

```
\savebuffer
  [prefix=no, file={temp/code.lua}, list=code]
```

successfully.

Comment: Thanks! This made me realize that the code in `t-filter` module could be improved: https://github.com/adityam/filter/commit/b718a46997ccb309655837c60462d1ad8242cd98 Earlier I was moving the file after it was being written.

Comment: @Aditya that's funny, the very reason I was looking into this is because I was experimenting with the `filter` module, and got to playing around with buffers.